# OpenGL changing uniform changes previous draw

Tags: c++, opengl, sdl, glad

I have this sample code

```
// EBO is just a rectangle
// copypasted from learnopengl
glClearColor(0.2f, 0.3f, 0.3f, 1.0f);
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

glUseProgram(shaderId);
glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, EBO);

glUniform1f(glGetUniformLocation(shaderId, shiftName), 0); //shiftName is string "shift"
glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, 6, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, 0);

glUniform1f(glGetUniformLocation(shaderId, shiftName), 0.5);
glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, 6, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, 0);

glFlush();
SDL_GL_SwapWindow(window);
```

Shaders that I have:
Vertex:

```
#version 330 core
layout (location = 0) in vec3 pos;

out vec4 vertexColor;
uniform float shift = 0;

void main()
{
    gl_Position = vec4(pos.x, pos.y - shift, pos.z, 1.0);
    vertexColor = vec4(0, shift, 0, 1.0);
}
```

Fragment:

```
#version 330 core
out vec4 FragColor;

in vec4 vertexColor;

void main()
{
    FragColor = vertexColor;
}
```

In my understanding, I should get two rectangles, one under another, with two colors, for each glDraw call. But instead I get one rectangle for second draw.
I assume, that both draw calls actually draw me one same rectangle. But I clearly don't understand why.
I tried flushing in between, creating second buffer, glUseProgram in between, etc.
You can see full code [here](https://gist.github.com/leviska/e2c2ebb15eeb0b7a076a7daa0398ba6d)

Comment: Where in the code did you specify two colours?

Comment: in vertex shader, `vertexColor = ...shift...`

Comment: " assume, that both draw calls actually draw me one same rectangle." Nothing in the information given in the question so far support that assumption. Please show the actual code to reproduce the problem.

Comment: @derhass I created gist with all my code here https://gist.github.com/leviska/e2c2ebb15eeb0b7a076a7daa0398ba6d

Comment: Please do not use links to the source code, add the _relevant_ sources **to the question itself**. In this particular case, it is not even the the question lacks the relevant part, it actually contains _wrong_ information which hides the error in the acutal source - which I have found.

Comment: @derhass I perfectly understand this and I would love to give you relevant code with error, but I don't know which part has the bug. In my understanding, the code that I gave should be relevant, but apparently it isn't.

Comment: Well, I tried to work around this issue by citing the relevant parts in the _answer_, but you should really follow [this guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) when you ask for debugging help on SO.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The *actual* source code triggering this issue was this:

> ```
> shader.Select();
> glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, EBO);
> shader.Set("shift", 0);
> glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, 6, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, 0);
> glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, EBO);        
> shader.Set("shift", 0.5f);         
> glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, 6, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, 0);
> ```

In conjunction with some shader class containging these methods:

> ```
> void Shader::Set(const std::string& name, bool value) const {
>   glUniform1i(glGetUniformLocation(id, name.c_str()), (int32_t)value);
> }
>
> void Shader::Set(const std::string& name, int32_t value) const {
>   glUniform1i(glGetUniformLocation(id, name.c_str()), value);
> }
>
> void Shader::Set(const std::string& name, float value) const {
>   glUniform1f(glGetUniformLocation(id, name.c_str()), value);
> }
> ```

This means that `shader.Set("shift", 0);` does call the `int32` overload, resulting in trying to use `glUniform1i` to set a `float` uniform, which will just produce a GL error and not change the uniform at all. THe first frame will acutally be correct since the uniform is intialized to 0 by default, but after that, it will stay on `0.5` forever. Use `shader.Set("shift", 0.0f);`, but IMO, that kind of overloads is doing more harm than good.

Side note: Those `glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, EBO);` calls are not necessary, the VAO will store the `GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BINDING`.

Comment: Ahhh, I see. Thanks, I tried everything with OpenGL and missed checking my own code